# Get the id of sub-collect parent document

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have collection of books with a sub-collection of users as in the uploaded picture.I have written a cloud function related with the sub collection 'users',such as if there is change in sub collection 'users',the trigger function will trigger.My problem is i can't figure out the the parent document id of the sub-collection 'users' in trigger function. How can i achieve this?.

for example:consider the scenario,According to picture

book(collection)==>my-book(doc)==>users(sub-collection)==>user-123(doc).

if there is any change in 'users' sub-collection,i would like to get the id of it's parent document,such as 'my-book'.[image: data-structure]

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Answer (score 0):

here what i got,

we will get the parent document id from  the context parameter

```
export const onChangesInBooksUserCollection = functions.firestore.document('books/{book}/users/{user}').onWrite.onWrite(async (snap, context) => {

//id of the parent document
const parentDocumentId:string=context.book;

//according to above picture parentDocumentId='my-book';

}
```